# Is there a way to make Excel IFS Function stop testing after the first TRUE result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below formula, however, whenever the value is 0 the result comes as #VALUE!
I would like to stop the function from testing once the first TRUE result is found, Help please.

```
=IFS(X6=0,"N/A",O6=0,"N/A",X6=O6,0,X6>O6,(X6-O6)/O6,X6<O6,(O6-X6)/X6,X6=0,"N/A",O6=0,"N/A")*100%
```

Comment: it returns `#VALUE` because you are trying to multiply a string `N/A` to a number `100%`.  You cannot do that.  `="N/A" * 100%` would result the same.  `IFS` does short circuit at the first true and ignores all else.

Comment: THANK YOU! Just removing the *100 solved it, not sure why when I tried this earlier it did not work or if I did it wrong.

Comment: You could keep the `*100%` and put `NA()` instead of `"N/A"`. `NA()` gives the `#N/A` special value, and `#N/A * 100% == #N/A`. Or… format the cell as a percentage?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFS(X6=0,"N/A",O6=0,"N/A",X6=O6,0,X6>O6,(X6-O6)/O6,X6<O6,(O6-X6)/X6,X6=0,"N/A",O6=0,"N/A")
```